# Why is Chrome connecting to wpad:80 and why is the connection hanging so long?

Tags: windows, proxy, google-chrome

I am using Socks5 using with [proxifire v3.21](https://www.proxifier.com/)
When I open Chrome, there are some **wpad** connections in proxifire with connecting status like below :

[image: wpad connecting]

What are these connections?
They cause one minute delay for google chrome to work.
In Firefox I have no problem at all.
Proxy settings in my machine is automatic.
Please give me some advice to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This is how the Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Protocol works

The idea behind the Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Protocol, or WPAD, is to allow a browser to automatically fetch proxy configuration data, by asking the DHCP server for it, and if that doesn't provide the necessary information, the local DNS server is asked.

This includes a query to an address just called `wpad`.

As to why this is so slow for you, no idea. It could be a variety of reasons. But you can also just simply disable proxy auto detection if you already know your proxy settings.

Comment: Please explain in your answer that "proxy auto detection" is in Internet Options of Internet Explorer.

Comment: It's not in Internet Explorer, it's in the Windows network setting. Chrome uses that, while Firefox uses its own setting.

Comment: @MechMK1; while it's been a hot minute since i've had to manage anything via Control Panel, Moonlight is running Windows 7 and i don't believe that particular setting was available in the Network and Sharing Center -- which is where most people's minds go to. on that note, though;
@MoonLight, Internet Options is actually a standard Windows settings dialog available through Control Panel -- Microsoft just gave easy access to it through IE since that's what file explorer was (is?) based off in the 9.x through XP days.

Comment: @EarthToAccess Correct - IE was (and still is) deeply embedded into Windows, which is also the reason you can't fully remove it. The IE settings *are* the Windows internet settings.